# Failed to apply unicode-escape in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, unicode-escapes

Cleaning tweet datasets by removing annoying character in bytecode (exp : \xf0\x9f\x99\x82)
Here's the code without using function :

```
b = data_tweet['Tweet']
b.head()

for i in b:
    x = i.encode('utf=8')
    y = x.decode('unicode-escape')
    print(y)
```

It worked. The character became : ðŸ™„, ðŸ¥°, etc.

But when I implemented it using function, in order to convert it in csv file. it failed. The byte character stays the same (exp : \xf0\x9f\x99\x82)
Here's the code :

```
def convert(text):
    for i in text:
        x = i.encode('utf=8')
        y = x.decode('unicode-escape')
        
    return text

convert(data_tweet['Tweet'])
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you actually didn't assign the result to `data_tweet['Tweet']`. You can use `apply()` on Series.

```py
def convert(text):
    x = text.encode('utf=8')
    y = x.decode('unicode-escape')
        
    return y

data_tweet['Tweet'] = data_tweet['Tweet'].apply(convert)
```

Or

```py
data_tweet['Tweet'] = data_tweet['Tweet'].apply(lambda text: text.encode('utf=8').decode('unicode-escape'))
```